# How to index a text field or make it searchable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, mariadb, substring, protein-database

I have stored about 7 million biological protein  sequences in `text` field of MySQL table (using `InnoDB` storage engine and `latin1_swedish_ci` collation).
Sequences stored in MySQL are simple combinations of English alphabets in uppercase. Like this:

```
MSTWQVYRLLMEYCSCLDNKTPNAFAKWCSSRKIKFLQADYFRKRPKHCDEGTGRYRSIYVMKKEYLGDIVRKITN
```

Selection of `text` field in MySQL looks essential because the sequences are trending from minimum 1 byte to maximum unlimited/unknown bytes (max size was 23089 in stored 7 million records but it will ideally go beyond for upcoming records in future).
Maximum key size for varchar or text in MySQL is `767`. Means that only first left most `767` bytes can be indexed.
`LIKE` operator ineffective on this index to efficiently retrieve `substring` from entire `text` field.

So, is there any way to index entire `text` field to efficiently search substrings inside it?

Comment: There is something called prefix index in mysql that can be leveraged. But it will support only the first 256 characters (thats the max). version 8 of mysql has full text index, but that comes with some gotchas.

Comment: You can try the SPHINX storage engine in MariaDB if you want to search for substrings. If you only need sorting - then perhaps you can split the strings into several columns, each column not larger than e.g. 256 symbols.

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong but at the end there is no optimization in speed for this type of search. Even if you have an index, the search ash to search for each and every string from the beginning to the end to find matching substring

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a few samples of your data. If it's `ACGTTTACTG` - style DNA sequence data, please tell us that.

Answer (score 0):

You're hoping to store, and then search for substrings, in [alphabetic protein sequences](http://web.mit.edu/meme_v4.11.4/share/doc/alphabets.html).

MySQL / MariaDB's search capabilities, both `LIKE '%CSCLDNKTPNAFAKW%'` and FULLTEXT, are **not suitable for this application**, sorry to say.

Why not?

- Searches with `LIKE '%CSCLDN%'` will be absurdly slow. (`%` in LIKE strings is the wildcard operator.)  And, a prefix index on your column won't help make things faster.
- FULLTEXT works on natural-language sequences of words, not the long strings of characters used to represent DNA sequences.

The [PostgreSQL RDBMS](https://www.postgresql.org/) has a feature called [trigram indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html). When you use it you can search long TEXT objects with  `LIKE '%ACTG%'` - style filters with decent performance. You can declare your trigram index using something like this.

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY table1_text ON table1
       USING GIN (textcolumn, gin_trgm_ops)
       INCLUDE (col1, col2, col3);
```

But before you do that you'll have to switch over to using postgreSQL.