# How to make search query in php faster?

Tags: php, laravel, database, search, query-optimization

I have a search function which works with a small amount of data, but after I filled the database with ten thousands of data, the site gets stuck on loading when I try to search for something.

```
pubblic function searchVideo(Request $request)
    {
        $searchTerm = $request->search;
        $videos = Videos::with(['tags:id', 'stars:id'])
            ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
            ->orWhereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
                $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
            })
            ->orWhereHas('stars', function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
                $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
            })
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(15);

        return $videos;
    }
```

If I delete

```
->orWhereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
                $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
            })
            ->orWhereHas('
stars', function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
                $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
            })
```

it works fine but then I wont get every result I wish to search for.

Comment: The tables which you are joining are stars and tags with specific field make that foreign key as well make them as index Key. Then try to fire your query.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this kind of query search term

```
 ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
```

which translates to SQL as

```
 WHERE title LIKE '%searchTerm%'
```

is a notorious query-performance antipattern. It can't random-access any ordinary BTREE index, but must rather scan through all the rows to find matching values. Fast on tiny testing databases. Slow on large production databases.

And, your query has the other notorious performance antipattern in it too:

```
ORDER BY something DESC LIMIT some_small_number
```

This means your RDBMS software must accumulate all matching rows, then sort them, then discard all but a small number of them. Slow.

What can you do about this? Here are a few suggestions that might help.

1. If you're on MySQL or MariaDB, make sure your `title` column is defined as `VARCHAR(767)` or some smaller number of characters. Don't define it as any kind of `TEXT`: access to those sorts of columns is slower.
2. Create a compound index as follows

   ```sql
   CREATE INDEX title_created ON video(title, created_at DESC);
   ```

   This will put the `title` column to be scanned in an index. That may be faster than scanning the entire table. And, the `created_at` column in the same index may make your `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` operation a bit faster.
3. Redesign your search operation to avoid leading `%` wildcards in `LIKE` clauses. Without the leading `%`, those operations can exploit indexes. I don't know enough about your application to give you advice about how to redesign your search, though.
4. Switch to using postgreSQL and use its [trigram indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72122832/how-to-index-a-text-field-or-make-it-searchable-in-mysql/72128739#72128739). They handle `LIKE '%searchterm%'` queries efficiently.

Comment: `ORDER BY something DESC LIMIT some_small_number` does not require the DB to collect all rows and sort all of them. This is a a basic CompSci 101 exercise; you use a fixed-size heap to keep track of the top N candidates seen so far. Any DB getting that wrong cannot be considered production quality.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
public function searchVideo(Request $request)
{
    $searchTerm = $request->search;
    $videos = Videos::with(['tags:id', 'stars:id'])
        ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
        ->orWhereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('pornstars', function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
        })
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->simplePaginate(15);

    return $videos;
}
```

Using 'like' instead of 'LIKE' invokes a Laravel method instead of an SQL operator.

The simplePaginate method instead of paginate, can be more efficient.

Can you use "select" to specify specific columns from the "videos" table, instead of loading all columns. For example:

```
    $videos = Videos::select('id', 'title', 'created_at')
        ->with(['tags:id', 'stars:id'])
```

Also you can use "orWhere" with Closure: Instead of using multiple orWhere methods, you can group them in a closure to avoid redundant query building. For example:

```
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
         $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
    })
```

Comment: the funny thing is, that my code works on the server, but doesnt work in localhost